# ionic v3 unable to display image from url - ion-img

Tags: image, rest, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an ionic version 3 app.

I am unable to display an image that is taken from http request. I am not sure why, the url is acquired for the image but it is not shown. It is only shown when I go to another page and back.

here is my code:

home.ts

```
  this.myapi.request('parent_student_info',data)
    .then(res =>{
        this.studentsarray = []
        this.studentsarray.push({
            id : response.employees[i].id,
            name: response.employees[i].first_name + " " + response.employees[i].last_name,
            face_image: response.employees[i].face_image_small
        })
```

home.html

```
  <ion-list *ngFor="let student of studentsarray" no-lines>
      <ion-row padding-left>
        <ion-col>                
            <ion-img width="70" height="70" src="{{student.face_image}}"></ion-img>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{student.name}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-list>
```

how can i make sure the image is loaded ? is it because of a delay in obtaining the url because of the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying the normal img tag instead of ion-img.

Comment: you are right, its terrible this ion-img tag. i got it working with img but is there a way to get it working with ion-img

Comment: To my knowledge, ion img is to be used when we have virtual scroll .
It says so in the documentation as well . 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/#img